# Python не видит заглавную букву в пути к python.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, файловые-пути

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всего способы перепробовал, в VS code не видит заглавную 'В' в пути к python.exe

Comment: так поставьте python в корень c:\ и не мучайтесь :)

Comment: Гений, вот чего чего, а до этого я не додумался, спасибо, работает)